# How do I get all Record fields and its values via reflection in Java 17?

Tags: java, reflection, java-record, java-17

I had a class:

```
class A {
   public final Integer orgId;
}
```

I replaced it with the record in Java 17:

```
record A (Integer orgId) {
}
```

Also, I had a code that did a validation via reflection that is working with the regular class, but doesn't work with the Records:

```
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields(); //getting empty array here for the record
for (Field field : fields) {
}
```

What would be the correct way to get the Record object fields and its values via reflection in Java 17?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
RecordComponent[] getRecordComponents()
```

You can retrieve name, type, generic type, annotations, and its accessor method from `RecordComponent`.

**Point.java:**

```
record Point(int x, int y) { }
```

**RecordDemo.java:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class RecordDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Point point = new Point(10,20);
        RecordComponent[] rc = Point.class.getRecordComponents();
        System.out.println(rc[0].getAccessor().invoke(point));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
```

Alternatively,

```
import java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class RecordDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Point point = new Point(10, 20);
        RecordComponent[] rc = Point.class.getRecordComponents();      
        Field field = Point.class.getDeclaredField(rc[0].getAccessor().getName());  
        field.setAccessible(true); 
        System.out.println(field.get(point));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `class` and `record` aren't equivalent: records have *private* fields.

[`Class#getFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()) returns *public* fields only.

You could use [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) instead.

Comment: getDeclaredFields() doesn't work. Returns empty array.

Comment: @DmitriyDumanskiy This is weird, I just tried locally with `record R(int i) {}`, I do get `[private final int R.i]` when calling `R.class.getDeclaredFields()`. I'm running Temurin's OpenJDK 17 on macOS. Which JDK are you running?

Comment: `getDeclaredFields()` does work.

Comment: @sp00m you're right. I misplaced with getFields() method.